# How to get design dialog properties in Sling model?

Tags: aem, sling-models

I have a design dialog where the values are getting stored in etc/design//. But now how should i read these property in Sling model?

Answer (score 1):

you could use script-bindings to get currentStyle -

```
@Inject @Source("script-bindings")
private Style currentStyle
```

then use -

```
currentStyle.get("<name of the text field>",String.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a `ResourceResolverFactory` then get a `ResourceResolver` and then obtain any property you need.